# SQL Optimization - calculating sales for current month by account manager

Tags: sql, optimization, query-optimization, visual-foxpro

I've written the below query but it runs incredibly slowly. Can anyone suggest how I can improve it or even push me in the right direction?

My goal is to list out the sales and cost for each sales territory in the current month (territory is basically account manager)

IT contains order lines

IH contains order headers (including the sales territory)

```
SELECT it.ih_terrtry                          AS terr, 
       Sum(it.it_exvat) / 100                 AS orderTotal, 
       Sum(it.it_cost * it.it_qtydelv) / 1000 AS orderCost 
FROM   (SELECT it.*, 
               iH.ih_terrtry 
        FROM   l_itran it 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN l_ihead ih 
                            ON ih.ih_doc = it.it_doc 
        WHERE  it.it_status = 'X' 
               AND Month(it_dtedelv) = Month(Datetime()) 
               AND Year(it_dtedelv) = Year(Datetime())) it 
GROUP  BY terr
```

Comment: Can you show us table and index definitions, and any explain/execution plan?

Comment: its visual fox pro

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into a compound index of multiple fields in VFP, I would suggest at a minimum, your l_itran table has an index on the it_dtedelv field only.  Can be compound, but that gets messy as a concatenated string and dtot() for date processes plus other fields.

Next, VFP can not optimize a query on dates if you are running a function on the different month/year parts.  Instead, create two variables that get to the beginning of the current month, and then to the beginning of the FOLLOWING month.  Ex:  Feb 1, 2019 and March 1, 2019.  This way you can get everything GREATER OR EQUAL to Feb 1, but LESS THAN March 1 which is inclusive of the last day of February up to 11:59:59pm if your date field is inclusive of time.

Also, you don't need to nest the queries by querying all records, then summing the results. This should be doable within one as I have below.  Final note/question to you.  Why do you have a LEFT JOIN to what appears to be the HEADER table to the transactions.  I would think there should ALWAYS be a header, but that's just me.

```
fromDate = TTOD( DATETIME()) - DAY( DATETIME()) + 1
toDate = GOMONTH(x,1)

SELECT ;
        iH.ih_terrtry Terr,;
        Sum(it.it_exvat) / 100 AS orderTotal, ;
        Sum(it.it_cost * it.it_qtydelv) / 1000 AS orderCost;
    FROM;
        l_itran it ;
            LEFT OUTER JOIN l_ihead ih ;
                ON it.it_doc = ih.ih_doc ;
    WHERE;
            it.it_dtedelv >= fromDate;
        AND it.it_dtedelv < toDate ;
        AND it.it_status = 'X' ;
    GROUP  BY ;
        iH.ih_terrtry
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, i'm teaching my self this as a go along. I've bought a few books and i'm doing the best I can and this has helped me a LOT.

Comment: @LewisMorris, can work/assist you with VFP.  If you would like more off-line from large posts, we can hit a chat room https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/882/programmers  Let me know.

Comment: That's very kind of you. I'm not internationally working with VFP.

Comment: Sorry I hadn't finished !!!   That's very kind of you. I'm not working with VFP intentionally, its just what the system we have at work uses, & when the standard reports didn't offer me what I wanted I started digging deeper. I'm trying to teach myself SQL and am currently reading a Wiley book on data analysis. I've taught myself VBA over the last few years (and become pretty proficient)and sort of see SQL it as the next step. But would love to understand more about all topics if you have the time one day.

Comment: @LewisMorris, go to the chat room (or here) and give me your email, then we can delete these comments after so it does not remain publicly visible.  Let me know.